# How to change default colors in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, colors, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Maybe my question was simple but I could not find any solution to that until now. I am using **Vuetify** in my **Nuxt** app. I used the dark theme of that. according to [Theme configuration](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/) of the official website we can change **primary** or **secondary** or other colors of the theme with our desired colors. But when we set for example **dark theme** the **default** text and background colors are set to white and black. I could not find any solution to change them. I know that we can set for example `class="primary"` to an element to change its background-color. But I want to set a default color for text or background like this:

```css
body {
    color: var(--v-info-base);
}
/* or */
#app {
    color: var(--v-info-base);
}
```

Where the colors of my website was defined in my nuxt.config.js file like this:

```js
vuetify: {
        customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
        theme: {
            dark: true,
            options: { customProperties: true },
            themes: {
                dark: {
                    primary: {
                        base: "#099b63",
                        darken1: "#04c279"
                    },
                    accent: "#250032",
                    secondary: "#97812F",
                    info: {
                        base: "#1FFFF1",
                        darken1: "#450b5a",
                        darken2: "#1125c0",
                        darken3: "#40bfa4"
                    },
                    warning: colors.amber.base,
                    error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
                    success: colors.green.accent3,
                    anchor: "#1FFFF1"
                }
            },
        }
    },
```

But that does not work for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

to achieve this you have to rewrite vuetify's sass variables, [example on how to use in the Doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#compilation-time)

so for example in your `variables.scss` you can have the following code:

```
$material-dark: (
  'background': #464994,
  'text': (
     'theme': #944646,
   )
);
```

this will rewrite the default colors for the background and text color in the dark mode.

Comment: I added your code to my ```variables.scss``` file, it changed the whole background-color, but the text is still white. I mean that for example when we have a ```v-text-field``` in our app and does not set any css to that, the default color text of them must be for example **#944646** and the default background-color must be **#464994** that you set, but this does not happen. I don't want to set alot of variables for each **'Vuetify component'**. because that is similar to set css on each component.

Comment: as far as I know the correct way to change the default styles in the whole vuetify app is through its variabla API. (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#variable-api). go to this link and in the drop down select the first item (`$vuetify`), scroll down to find `$material-dark` then find desired section and modify them to your needs. for example you have `$material-dark: ('text-fields': ('filled': '#someColor'))` or `$material-dark: ('inputs': ('box': '#someColor'))` or . `$material-dark: ('text-color': '#someColor')`

Comment: I believe another approach would be to inspect each element to find the css styles in browser's dev tools then copy each css selector and try to modify it with `!important` css styles which isn't a clean solution and is more tedious. I suggest you experiment further with the said variables to find the ones that suits your needs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot to recolor some components of my app. But I expected that when we changed the color of ```body```, all components understand it automatically, unfortunately the structure of **Vuetify** is different and does not allow us to do that.